# What's a good design practice if I want to overload an inherited method from a super class?

Tags: java, overloading

I have 2 concrete classes and an abstract superclass. The abstract superclass has an abstract method named play() which accepts two arguments and returns a type String. When implementing the play() method on the Robot class, I don't want to use the default method signature, hence I overloaded it. But how do I hide the overridden method? Any good design practices?

```
    abstract class Player {
        public abstract String play(String gesture, Robot p2);
    }
```

```
    class Human extends Player {
        @Override
        public String play(String gesture, Robot p2) {
          //code here
          return "player code";
        }
    }
```

```
    class Robot extends Player {
        @Override
        public String play(String gesture, Robot p2) {
          //I don't want to use this method but I need to implement this
          return null;
        }

        public String play() {
          //this is the method that I want to use
          return "robot code";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is your Robot class extending Player?  If you have to extend Player, throw an exception in the overridden method.  Also, you can return "robot code" from the overridden method and ignore the input parameters.

Comment: "`//this is the method that I want to use`", then use it and ignore the other. Hiding the other method doesn't make sense. By extending `Player` you are saying that the extending class *is a* `Player`. Therefore, all `Player`s are supposed to be able to `play(String gesture, Robot p2)`. If you don't want that, change your design rather than thinking about hiding anything.

Comment: Your robot player needs to implement the same interface, or you break the Liskov substitution principle. If you don't need the parameter values you can ignore them, but you **must** accept them.

Comment: Assuming you have a good reason for doing it this way: Making the overridden method throw an UnsupportedOperationException is probably the most idiomatic way of doing this.